# Test Cases fails if any of them fails

Tags: mocha.js

I am trying mocha test case to check rest api, but the issue is if I have 3 test cases and first one fails then rest are not executing. It stops at first only.

Here is following code:

```
describe('suite 1',function(){
  it('tc1',function(done){
     // some test case with failure
       should([1]).equal([]);
       done();
  })

  it('tc2',function(done){
     // some test case with success
       should([]).equal([]);
       done();
  })
```

})

In above code I am not able to get report like
2 test cases.
1 Passed.
1 Fail.

It fails in middle, in here  it fails on first test case only.

Answer (score 0):

Both tests are failing because they both **should fail**.

The both tests fail because you are using `equal` which checks for object **identity**. That is, it uses `===` to check for the equality. Now, open an interactive Node session and try this:

```
[] === []
```

You'll get `false`. That's because each new empty array is a new JavaScript object and `===` will be true only if the two arrays are the same object.

Note that you get the result you expect in your first test but not for the reason you (probably) think. The test fails for the same reason I've just explained. The fact that one array contains an element but the other is empty is not taken into account by `should`.

You should use `eql` to test whether the arrays have the same members.